# How to get current working directory in R?

Tags: r

1. How to get current working dir?
   I guess there should be a command like getcwd(), however, I can't find something like this in the documens.
2. How to change to another dir?
3. How to set default working dir when I start R?

   version
                  _
   platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32
   arch           x86_64
   os             mingw32
   system         x86_64, mingw32
   status
   major          3
   minor          1.0
   year           2014
   month          04
   day            10
   svn rev        65387
   language       R
   version.string R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
   nickname       Spring Dance

Thanks!

Comment: Please try a simple google search before posting! Typing "r get current working directory" gets me the man page answering your first two questions as its first hit.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. It is `getwd()`
2. It is `setwd("path/to/new/dir")`
3. Either via a Windows property, or via `.Rprofile` etc, or (as I recall) by defining `$HOME` which Windows does not set by default.  See `help(Startup)`.

Answer (score 5):

As a complement to @Dirk's answer, I would like to add something that might be useful and is frequently overlooked.
It is possible to save the current working directory and set the new one *at the same time*.

Function `setwd` returns the working directory so all you have to do is to save its value. This can be useful if you, at a later moment, need to return to the original working directory.

```
old_dir <- setwd("/path/to/new/dir")

#[run the code you want]

setwd(old_dir)
```