# Why does 'getwd' not tell me the working directory?

Tags: r, ubuntu

I am somewhat new to coding and have not come across this issue before. I am using R in an ubuntu shell when I attempt to find or set my working directory the functions returns this:

```
 > getwd
function ()
.Internal(getwd())
bytecode: 0x3db9f40
environment: namespace:base

> setwd
function (dir)
.Internal(setwd(dir))
bytecode: 0x50020f8
environment: namespace:base
```

What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: Call the function by `getwd()`, not to print the function by `getwd`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get current working directory in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23819938/how-to-get-current-working-directory-in-r)

Answer (score 1):

As 李哲源 mentioned in a comment try using brackets after the function name :)

`getwd()` instead of `getwd`; and
`setwd()` instead of `setwd`.

In R you can call the function name (without brackets) to print info about the functions definition, its environment and etc.
But calling the function it self must be with brackets.

To set the working directory you can use the following (as an example):

```
setwd("/home/myName/myFolder/")
```

**Edit.**

Note that you can save the current working directory and set the new one *at the same time*. Function `setwd` returns the working directory so all you have to do is to save it. This can be useful if you, at a later moment, need to return to the original working directory.

```
old_dir <- setwd("/home/myName/myFolder/")

#[run the code you want]

setwd(old_dir)
```